# Http is not running under Visual Studio IIS Express

Tags: http, iis-express

I am experiencing a strange problem. I have an ASP.Net Web API solution project. The solution was opened and running perfectly. Then the system automatically restarted due to a pending windows update. After that when I started the solution and ran the Web API project, it only runs on https and I even cant see the http url in Show All Applications on IIS express.

[image]

[image]

While in applicationhost.config, it contains the following bindings:

```
<site name="BevahiorApp.API" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\BevahiorApp.API\BevahiorApp.API" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50145:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44378:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

and in the Project properties under Web tab

[image]

Comment: You can continue accessing that HTTP URL as long as it matches the binding in IIS Express config file. It is just VS and the tray app that prefer to show only HTTPS URL as you probably enabled HTTPS. The trend is to provide only HTTPS links (everywhere over the internet), so Microsoft didn't make complex UI elements to show all site bindings you configured in the config file.

Comment: @LexLi No that did not work. And even that does not look logical. However the issue is resolved. I have changed the port no. in Project URL under Web tab in project properties and created new virtual directory and it worked.